# Yii2 Dynagrid: How to implement Sortable to sort the rows

Tags: yii2

In [Dynagrid](http://demos.krajee.com/dynagrid) it is possible to use [Sortable](http://demos.krajee.com/sortable) to sort the columns. I need to enable sorting rows, which should work similarly:

[image]

Is there a way to implement such sorting directly in Dynagrid or do I have to programm the sorting separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable the sorting is simple:

```
$('tbody').sortable();
```

The only problem is to save the sorting to the database. I have decided to save it after a click on a button (and not with ajax) in views/sorted-table/index.php:

```
if (strpos(Url::current(), 'sort') === false) {
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'sort-form',
    ]);
    echo '<input type="hidden" id="field-sort" name="sort" value="">';
    if (isset($sortMessage) && $sortMessage != '') {
        echo '<p>' . $sortMessage . '</p>';
    }
    echo Html::submitButton(Icon::show('floppy-o') . 'Sortierung speichern', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
    ActiveForm::end();

    DynagridSortAsset::register($this);
}
```

The positions of rows are saved in the hidden input field by jQuery:

```
$('.btn-primary').mousedown(function() {
    var sorting = "";
    $('.sortable-row').each( function (index, value) {
        sorting += $(this).attr('data-id') + ':' + $(this).attr('data-sortierung') +',';
    });

    $('#field-sortierung').val(sorting);
});
```

The values are then in controller processed and saved to the database.